# Can Excel 2007 Forms Toggle Button Depressed Effect Be Modified?

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to be able to configure an Excel 2007 forms toggle button (not ActiveX) with different pictures for its "Up" state and its "Depressed" state.  I'd also like to get rid of the ugly screening effect that occurs when the toggle button is depressed.  I know how to copy and paste a picture into the Picture property of the toggle button, and I know how to load a picture file from disk into the Picture property. I don't know if the forms toggle button supports individual pictures for each of its two states.  I'm fluent in VBA.  I'd like to be able to control the display of pictures in both the "Up" and "Depressed" states and not have the "Depressed" state picture screened.

Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for catching this.  I've corrected the title to reflect a forms control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a toggle button with image, why not just use a picture and make the property **SpecialEffect** to **`0 - fmSpecialEffectRaised`** for depressed, and **`fmSpecialEffectSunken`** for up state?

Use the `_Click()` code to change the SpecialEffect state and the picture to use.

The idea is there, let us know if you have trouble in code then post new question.

---

I had some fun, here's screenshot and code.

The userform is like this Initial, Clicked once, Clicked again:
[image: Init][image: ImagePressed][image: ImageDepressed]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Image1_Click()
    Const sImgPressed = "C:\Test\ubuntu.gif"
    Const sImgDePressed = "C:\Test\motorola.gif"

    With Image1
        Select Case .SpecialEffect
            Case fmSpecialEffectRaised
                .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
                .Picture = LoadPicture(sImgPressed)
                Me.TextBox1.Value = "Image is pressed"
            Case fmSpecialEffectSunken
                .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectRaised
                .Picture = LoadPicture(sImgDePressed)
                Me.TextBox1.Value = "Image is Depressed"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Patrick, for taking the time to post this!  I think you are on to something that will work perfectly.  I'll give this a go this morning and report back.

Comment: That worked perfectly, Patrick!  I was able to create a toggle button that works perfectly and looks modern using graphics I created in Illustrator.  I have been searching for the past two days for a solution to the outdated look of Excel 2007's controls and your solution enabled me do that for the toggle button.